# I have a problem in Isabelle related to 'Clash of types' that I am unable to solve. Could someone help me?

Tags: function, types, partial, isabelle, proof

I would want to formalise a calculus in Isabelle. I started with this definitions:

---

type_synonym Signature =  "string ⇀ nat"

type_synonym 'a Interpretation = "string ⇀ 'a list set"

datatype 'a Structure =  Structure "Signature" "'a set"  "'a Interpretation"

fun getNat :: "'a Structure ⇒ string ⇒ nat option" where
"getNat (Structure sig _ _) w = sig w"

fun getModels :: "'a Structure ⇒ string ⇒ 'a list set option" where
"getModels (Structure _ _ models) w = models w"

fun getDomain :: "'a Structure ⇒ 'a set" where
"getDomain (Structure _ relations _)  = relations"

---

I realised the functions need the types 'nat option' and 'set option'. I think this is because 'Signature' and 'Interpretation' are partial functions. However, when I try to define the next function, there is a problem that I cannot fix.

---

```
fun wfStructure :: "'a Structure  ⇒ bool " where 
"wfStructure Structure sig relations models = 
( 
    relations ≠ {} ) ∧ 
    (∀r. r ∈ dom(sig) ⟶ ( r ∈ dom(models)  ∧ 
                            (∀t. t ∈ (models r) ⟶ length(t) = (sig r)
                          )
    )
)"
```

---

Comment: You want `wfStructure (Structure sig relations models)` with the parenthesis

Comment: Wait, you know the difference between `type_synonym Signature = "string ⇀ nat"` and `type_synonym Signature = "string ⇒ nat"` and you picked the first on purpose right? (because that is why you need the options, it has nothing to do with partial functions).

Comment: Thank you!. I have another problem. I want to define the restriction of a function to a smaller domain. This is my definition: